# Sharepoint 2010 SPWorkflowManager.CancelWorkflow Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, access-denied

I am trying to execute the following code in the page code behind

```
var workflow = GetWorkflowInstance();
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
                () => SPWorkflowManager.CancelWorkflow(worklow));
```

Despite RunWithElevatedPrivileges i got "Access denied" exception.

What i forgot to configure? Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't sharepoint.stackexchange.com a better place for this question?

Answer (score 0):

add `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` before cancelWorkflow()

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPWorkflowManager.CancelWorkflow(worklow)
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
});
```